# Entity Relationship Diagram for Hotel

Tags: erd

I tried creating an ERD model for hotel reservation and billing. Are the cardinalities correct, I'm a bit confused about that. And are there any attributes that are not in the right place? If someone could help me and go over this I would appreciate it. Thank you.

[image: Hotel ERD]

Answer (score 2):

This looks mostly complete, though the `BookingID` field in `Guest` seems a little pessimistic. What will you do if a guest wants to stay at the hotel again in the future? As you already have a relation between `Guest` and `Booking` via `GuestID`, you can probably remove `BookingID` from `Guest`. A similar thing can be done in `Bill` as, if you know the `BookingID` then you know the `GuestID`. So `GuestID` can be removed from `Bill` … if you choose, of course. You don’t *need* to make either change.

Answer (score 1):

You make [RoomNo] as PK,
so, [RoomNo]=1 can only assigned to [HotelCode]=H1
so, [RoomNo]=1 cannot assgin to new [HotelCode]=H2 -> violate PK of [Room] table

Answer (score 0):

I would say everything looks great but you should remove fk from the `guest` for `bookingid`. And the connection between `bill` and the `guest` should not be there, as you can have those information via booking entity.

Answer (score -2):

Yes the cardinalities look completely fine on this ERD.

I am a bit confused about the "Booking" to "Bill" cardinality (although this could be a gap in my domain knowledge on hotel operations).

In what instances would you have multiple "Bills" per a singular "Booking"?